# Is per-request, stateless HTTP Basic/Digest authentication possible in CakePHP 2.0?

Tags: php, api, authentication, rest, cakephp-2.0

The manual is unclear as to how to implement this (it assumes you already know what exactly you're doing and in some cases feels like an afterthought), and I've been scratching my head for a fair while trying to figure it out.

### The problem: authentication via HTTP auth headers for all API requests

As far as I've been able to test, I can use Basic auth and the normal form based login in CakePHP, but **only** by first hitting up the `login` action I define in the Auth component. This is fine when I'm accessing the site directly, and works as expected (with the exception of Digest, which appears to be utterly buggered). Via cURL, though, I've had no luck unless I'm already logged in.

Obviously, for an API, this is far from ideal. I don't want to post a request to `/login` before doing what I want to do, and I can't expect a user to log in manually so Cake has a cookie to read. It needs to be stateless.

Any attempt to supply authentication credentials along with each request I make (via cURL) is ignored and I get a 403 error in return. Neither the `login` method or any of the `Auth` classes are touched.

What do I need to do to make Cake behave like an actual API and allow me to authorise statelessly on a per request basis? Am I going to have to roll my own solution?

Comment: Most APIs don't work like this.  You can recommend that people use cURL's cookie support (e.g. `--cookie-jar`) or implement some kind of authentication token, like [Flickr's API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.spec.html)

Comment: A non Cake based REST API I implemented used HTTP basic for auth, with login details supplied with every request. Much like how Twitter's started out.

Comment: Stumbled upon this question as I was having the issue myself, I seemed to have solved it and will post my answer soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a centralized API that allows for user authentication via HTTP Digest and requires users to login for many user related functions. The way CakePHP forces a login is by checking if the action requires login, redirecting to your login action (defaults to /users/login), then you can redirect back.

I created my API by doing the following:

```
//Config/routes.php
///////////////////////////
/**
 * Users Controller routes for REST API 
 */
    Router::mapResources('users');
/**
 * Parses extensions for data serialization 
 */
    Router::parseExtensions();

//Controller/UserController.php
////////////////////////////////
<?php

App::uses('DigestAuthenticate', 'Controller/Component/Auth/');

class UsersController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Users';

    //Login callback
    function login() {
        //dont render for login, just a call back for auth
        $this->autoRender = false;

        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        }
    }

    //GET /users.[xml|json]
    //this is the basic call that tests user authentication
    //basically a login then echo
    function index() {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $user = $this->Auth->user();

            $this->User->id = $user['id'];
            $this->User->saveField('last_login', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

            $this->set('response', array(
                'response' => array(
                    'code' => 'users_auth_success',
                    'message' => 'User has passed authentication',
                    'data' => $user
                )
            ));
            //will serialize to xml or json based on extension
            $this->set('_serialize', 'response');
        } 
    }
}

?>
```

You can then use this API in something like:

```
$c = curl_init($uri . '.' . $this->_format);

curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $login['user'] . ':' . $login['pass']);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$response = curl_exec($c);
$info = curl_getinfo($c);

curl_close($c);

if($info['http_code'] == $this->_http_codes['OK']) {
    //success
    if($this->_format == 'xml')
        $response = Xml::toArray(Xml::build($response));
    else//JSON
        $response = json_decode($response);
        return $response['response']['data'];
} else if($info['http_code'] == $this->_http_codes['Unauthorized']) {
    return false;
} else {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is great. I had almost the same implementation, but probably couldn't see the wood for the trees. Thanks!