# CakePHP and RESTful with PhoneGap

Tags: api, rest, cakephp, cordova

I have built a cakephp site with RESTFul calls. Happy to say these calls work when using curl from another php site. (This is all testing at the moment)

The next stage is setting up authorization, from my understand I'd be looking at either basic or digest loging to make RESTful calls.

1. I'd like to build a phonegap app, that requires login. Would RESTful calls to CakePHP be the way to go. i.e making a RESTful API for my site?
2. I'd like to provide an API key. How would this key be secured in a phonegap app?
3. How secure is phonegap in general? If the files for an app are css, html, js can't the app be broken into and the files revealed

Just looking for general advice and a direction to continue researching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you need would be a [stateless authentication system](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-stateless-authentication-systems). CakePHP comes with 2 built in. Take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9970464/372875)